# Motor Oil in Coolant Reserve

Tags: oil, coolant, cooling-system, mercedes-benz

2004 Mercedes E500 - Yes, I am sure of it. In a moment of stupidity, I added about 8oz of motor oil to the coolant reserve. I have heard nothing will happen and I've also heard it can mess up the radiator. I have not started the engine yet - this just happened. How much trouble am I in? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have the coolant reservoir flushed and replace it with new coolant.